# How to restart merge for a "pull --rebase" conflict

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am working on a Git plug-in based on JGit from the Eclipse Foundation, and I already had "*Restart merge*" implemented by a colleague for when conflicts occurred while trying to execute the default pull (with merge).

Now I am working on a "*Pull (rebase)*" action. When conflicts happen and the user makes some changes inside the conflicting file, I would like to let them be able restart the merge. I've noticed that some Git clients don't have this option (EGit for Eclipse, GitKraken Free), while some have it (SourceTree).

My current code looks like this:

```
public void restartMerge() {
    try {
      RepositoryState repositoryState = getRepository().getRepositoryState();
      String revision = repositoryState == RepositoryState.REBASING_MERGE ? "HEAD" : "MERGE_HEAD";
      AnyObjectId commitToMerge = getRepository().resolve(revision);
      git.clean().call();
      git.reset().setMode(ResetType.HARD).call();

      if (repositoryState == RepositoryState.REBASING_MERGE) {
        // TODO: regenerate the conflict
      } else {
        git.merge().include(commitToMerge).setStrategy(MergeStrategy.RECURSIVE).call();
      }

      fireFileStateChanged(new ChangeEvent(GitCommand.MERGE_RESTART, Collections.<String> emptyList()));
    } catch (IOException | NoRepositorySelected | GitAPIException e) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(e, e);
        }
    }
}
```

I think I have to do a rebase again, or something like that, to re-generate the conflict, just as my colleague did a new `merge()`. But at this point I am on a detached HEAD... I tried moving to the `master` branch and rebasing again having `origin/master` as the upstream, but it didn't work...

What would the Git commands be for restarting a rebase conflict? Perhaps I can execute them using JGit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, `git pull` is basically:

- run `git fetch`
- then run a second Git command, usually but not always `git merge`

The merge can stop with conflicts.  You can either allow the user to fix the conflicts and resume, or abort the merge and put everything back to the way it was before the merge started:

- To allow the user to resume after manually fixing conflicts, you simply invoke either `git merge --continue` or `git commit`: the `git merge --continue` itself verifies that there's an in-progress merge in which the conflicts are fixed, and then invokes `git commit`.
- To abort and put things back the way they were after the fetch but before the merge, you can use `git merge --abort` or `git reset --merge` (these do the same thing).

The second command, though, can be `git rebase`, which can also stop with conflicts.  It can even be `git read-tree`, in some corner cases.  Because you have so little control when using `git pull`, I'd recommend *never* using it programmatically: if you're writing code that runs Git commands, *always* split up your operation into `git fetch` and your own programmatically-chosen second Git command, so that you know what second command you run.

The problem with rebase, though, is that it is essentially built out of a series of `git cherry-pick` operations.  (Depending on how you invoke `git rebase`, this may actually be `git apply --3way` rather than `git cherry-pick`, or it may literally run `git cherry-pick`.)  *Each* cherry-pick operations can stop with a merge conflict.  So you don't just have one conflict, but *M* conflicts, *M ≤ N*, where *N* is the number of commits being copied into their new position by the rebase.

To resume rebasing after the user fixes up conflicts, invoke `git rebase --continue`.  This verifies that there's an ongoing rebase and that the conflicts are fixed, and commits them and moves on to the next cherry-pick operation.  The rebasing continues until it either hits another merge conflict, or has completed all cherry-picks; after completing the last cherry-pick, the rebase reassigns the branch name's value to the last-copied commit, and re-attaches `HEAD` to the branch name.

If you use `git rebase --abort`, you tell Git to stop the cherry-picking operations (including all the ones not yet started) and go back to the state you were in before *any* of them started.  If you allow users to resolve merge conflicts, note that this discards *all* the resolved-so-far cherry-picks, including all the work the user did to resolve conflicts.  If the user has enabled `git rerere`, the resolved-so-far merges' results are recorded in the re-use cache, so this is not always too terrible.

There are no great solutions to merge conflicts.  If there were a way to automate this reliably, Git would already do it.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, your recommendation would be to avoid implementing such a "Restart merge" action for rebase conflicts, right? If there is no (easy) way to restart the merge for each conflicted file, than I do agree that restarting should be avoided. Moreover, I noticed that even SourceTree, which has such an action, sometimes doesn't do anything when invoking it. For example, if I resolve the conflict using "theirs" (i.e. the working branch), but then I change my mind and invoke "Restart merge", nothing happens. The file remains unchanged.

Comment: The idea is that I started seriously considering giving up on the "Restart merge" action. If the user changes their mind and don't want to keep their current trial of resolving the conflict, they should probably manually abort the rebase and `pull --rebase` action. Do you have another/better approach?

Comment: Git's approach is to stop in the middle of each failed merge and have you run another command after you have done whatever it takes to fix that, or run the `--abort` variety of the command to terminate-and-roll-back-to-start. You can offer the same kind of thing, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run `git rebase --abort`, and restart your rebase using `git pull --rebase` in your case.

Comment: Yes, that's a way to do it, but I don't know if it's the preferred one. If I understand correctly, the fetch has been executed successfully, and only the rebase failed. I would like to avoid fetching again, for performance reasons.

Comment: I don't think that will be much of a trouble. It's true that `git fetch` will be run again, but in this particular feature you're trying to implement the user will relaunch it within seconds, which is a short period of time, in which mostly likely changes won't be introduced: means the second `fetch` will be fairly fast. If I was you, I will first make it work,  and then bother myself with performance problems if they arise.